# Looping through Regex Matches

Tags: c#, .net, regex, foreach

This is my source string:

```
<box><3>
<table><1>
<chair><8>
```

This is my Regex Patern:

```
<(?<item>\w+?)><(?<count>\d+?)>
```

This is my Item class

```
class Item
{
    string Name;
    int count;
    //(...)
}
```

This is my Item Collection;

```
List<Item> OrderList = new List(Item);
```

I want to populate that list with Item's based on source string.
This is my function. It's not working.

```
Regex ItemRegex = new Regex(@"<(?<item>\w+?)><(?<count>\d+?)>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            foreach (Match ItemMatch in ItemRegex.Matches(sourceString))
            {
                Item temp = new Item(ItemMatch.Groups["item"].ToString(), int.Parse(ItemMatch.Groups["count"].ToString()));
                OrderList.Add(temp);
            }
```

Threre might be some small mistakes like missing letter it this example because this is easier version of what I have in my app.

The problem is that In the end I have only one Item in OrderList.

**UPDATE**

I got it working.
Thans for help.

Comment: Just ran it - works like expected (3 items in the list).

Comment: Can you share it? Might help someone if he is running into the same problem.

Comment: @ChrisWue It was mistake in my application code. Not helpful.

Comment: Some code on understanding and accessing regex matches can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27444808/546871

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceString = @"<box><3>
<table><1>
<chair><8>";
        Regex ItemRegex = new Regex(@"<(?<item>\w+?)><(?<count>\d+?)>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        foreach (Match ItemMatch in ItemRegex.Matches(sourceString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ItemMatch);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Returns 3 matches for me. Your problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 13):

For future reference I want to document the above code converted to using a declarative approach as a LinqPad code snippet:

```
var sourceString = @"<box><3>
<table><1>
<chair><8>";
var count = 0;
var ItemRegex = new Regex(@"<(?<item>[^>]+)><(?<count>[^>]*)>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var OrderList = ItemRegex.Matches(sourceString)
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => new
                    {
                        Name = m.Groups["item"].ToString(),
                        Count = int.TryParse(m.Groups["count"].ToString(), out count) ? count : 0,
                    })
                    .ToList();
OrderList.Dump();
```

With output:

[image: List of matches]

Comment: What program is on that screenshot? Is it your own program?

Comment: That's generated by LinqPad's Dump() extension method. You can stick Dump() on the end of most objects and it will output a formatted representation of the object. LinqPad is just an exceptional tool for writing/evaluating C# code http://www.linqpad.net/. The above code can be copied and pasted straight into LinqPad and it will generate the table.