# Convert result of matches from regex into list of string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I convert the list of match result from regex into `List<string>`? I have this function but it always generate an exception,

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match'
>   to type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.CaptureCollection'.

```
public static List<string> ExtractMatch(string content, string pattern)
{
    List<string> _returnValue = new List<string>();
    Match _matchList = Regex.Match(content, pattern);
    while (_matchList.Success)
    {
        foreach (Group _group in _matchList.Groups)
        {
            foreach (CaptureCollection _captures in _group.Captures) // error
            {
                foreach (Capture _cap in _captures)
                {
                    _returnValue.Add(_cap.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return _returnValue;
}
```

If I have this string,

```
I have a dog and a cat.
```

regex

```
dog|cat
```

I want that the function will return of result into `List<string>`

```
dog
cat
```

Comment: This previous answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767605/looping-through-regex-matches

Comment: did try that but i always get `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' because 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

With the Regex you have, you need to use `Regex.Matches` to get the final list of strings like you want:

```
MatchCollection matchList = Regex.Matches(Content, Pattern);
var list = matchList.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: to retain multiple groups, see my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/21123574/1037948

Answer (score 17):

To get just a list of Regex matches, you may:

```
var lookfor = @"something (with) multiple (pattern) (groups)";
var found = Regex.Matches(source, lookfor, regexoptions);
var captured = found
                // linq-ify into list
                .Cast<Match>()
                // flatten to single list
                .SelectMany(o =>
                    // linq-ify
                    o.Groups.Cast<Capture>()
                        // don't need the pattern
                        .Skip(1)
                        // select what you wanted
                        .Select(c => c.Value));
```

This will "flatten" all the captured values down to a single list.  To maintain capture groups, use `Select` rather than `SelectMany` to get a list of lists.

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution using Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

static class Program {
    static void Main(string[] aargs) {
        string value = "I have a dog and a cat.";
        Regex regex = new Regex("dog|cat");
        var matchesList = (from Match m in regex.Matches(value) select m.Value).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that will fit into your code well.

```
while (_matchList.Success)
{
    _returnValue.Add(_matchList.Value);
    _matchList = _matchList.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Historically the Regex collections have not implemented the generic collection interfaces, and the LINQ extension methods you're using operate on the generic interfaces. MatchCollection was updated in .NET Core to implement IList, and thus can be used with the Selectextension method, but when you move to .NET Standard 2.0, that interface implementation isn't there, and thus you can't just callSelect. Instead, you'll need to use the `LINQ` `Cast` or `OfType` extensions to convert to an `IEnumerable`, and then you can use `Select` on that. Hope that helps.

Example

```
Regex wordMatcher = new Regex(@"\p{L}+");
return wordMatcher.Matches(text).Cast<Match>().Select(c => c.Value);

Regex wordMatcher = new Regex(@"\p{L}+");
return wordMatcher.Matches(text).OfType<Match>().Select(c => c.Value);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var regex = new Regex("{([A-Za-z])*}");
var result= regex.Matches(text).Where(p => p.Success).Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```