# how to extract a whole sentence by a single word match in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, text-segmentation

So I have got a whole string (about 10k chars) and then searching for a word(or many words) in that string. With `regex(word).Matches(scrappedstring)`.

But how to do so to extract the whole sentence, that contains that word. I was thinking of taking a substring after the searched word until the first dot/exclamation mark/question mark/etc. But how to take the part of the sentence before the searched word ?

Or maybe there's a better logic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your boundaries are e.g. `.`, `!`, `?` and `;`, match all sentences across `[^.!?;]*(wordmatch)[^.!?;]*` expression.
It will give all sentences with desired *wordmatch* inside.

Example:

```
var s = "First sentence. Second with wordmatch ? Third one; The last wordmatch, EOM!";
var r = new Regex("[^.!?;]*(wordmatch)[^.!?;]*");
var m = r.Matches(s);

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, m.Count).Select(index => m[index].Value).ToList();
```

Comment: I used some of your suggestion here plus the chosen answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767605/looping-through-regex-matches

Answer (score 0):

You can get substrings between sentence finishers (dot/exclamation mark/qustion mark/etc) and search for the word in each sentence inside a loop.

Then return the substring when you find the matching word.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a position, you would then read up to the next `.`, or end of the file.. but you also need to read *backwards* from the beginning of the word to a `.` or the beginning of the file.  Those two positions mean you can then extract the sentence.

Note, it's not fool-proof...  in its simplest form as outlined above `e.g.` would mean the sentence started after the `g.` which is not probably the case.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the sentances from the input. Then search for the specified word(s) within each sentance.
Return the sentances where the word(s) is present.

```
    public List<string> GetMatchedString(string match, string input)
    {
        var sentanceList = input.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!' });
        var regex = new Regex(match);
        return sentanceList.Where(sentance => regex.Matches(sentance,0).Count > 0).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a process in 2 steps.

1st you fragment the phrases and then filter each one has the word.

something like this:

```
var input = "A large text with many sentences. Many chars in a string!. A sentence without the pattern word.";

//Step 1: fragment phrase.
var patternPhrase = @"(?<=(^|[.!?]\s*))[^ .!?][^.!?]+[.!?]";

//Step 2: filter out only the phrases containing the word.
var patternWord = @"many";

var result = Regex
    .Matches(input, patternPhrase) // step 1
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(s => s.Value)
    .Where(w => Regex.IsMatch(w, patternWord, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)); // step 2

foreach (var item in result)
{
    //do something with any phrase.
}
```