# Extract sentence containing a word from text

Tags: c#, regex

I have a large text. I need find any word in the text then copy to variable the phrase that contains the word. How can I do this by C#? Maybe I can use some regular expression?

Comment: So to clarify, if you search for "Hello", it will copy the "phrase" "Hello World." from "Testing 123. Hello World. This is a Test" into a variable?

Comment: Cyral, yes, exactly!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521057/how-to-extract-a-whole-sentence-by-a-single-word-match-in-a-string

Comment: @EmmadKareem: phrase is not equal to a sentence, but it is related. Even sentences would be difficult to handle for each language (as for instance Spanish has unnatural questions marks for an English person, just for one of thoe), let alone phrase. I guess the OP only needs English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the regex expression `[^.!?;]*(search)[^.?!;]*[.?!;]`, where "search" is your query.

```
string query = "professional";
var regex = new Regex(string.Format("[^.!?;]*({0})[^.?!;]*[.?!;]", query));
string text =
    @"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. 
    It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites.
    With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to 
    every question about programming.";

var results = regex.Matches(text);

for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(results[i].Value.Trim());
```

This code uses the regex to find all sentences containing "professional", and outputs them, trimming any whitespace.

Output: `Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.`

Comment: This code has an error. `Fix string.Trim(results[i].Value)` to `results[i].Value.Trim()` as Trim is not a static function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, missed the `string.`

Comment: that's a nice regex, as cryptic and powerful as it can be

Comment: Can anyone suggest a regex to properly extract sentences containing decimals? ('.' shouldn't be treated as fullstop in '5.25ml')