# How to read RegEx Captures in C#

Tags: c#, regex, console

I want to ask a user for their phone number in the console, check it against a RegEx, then capture the digits so I can format them the way I want. I've got all that working except the RegEx capture part. How do I get the capture values into C# variables?

```
static void askPhoneNumber()
{
    String pattern = @"[(]?(\d{3})[)]?[ -.]?(\d{3})[ -.]?(\d{4})";

    System.Console.WriteLine("What is your phone number?");
    String phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();

    while (!Regex.IsMatch(phoneNumber, pattern))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bad Input");
        phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Match match = Regex.Match(phoneNumber, pattern);
    Capture capture = match.Groups.Captures;

    System.Console.WriteLine(capture[1].Value + "-" + capture[2].Value + "-" + capture[3].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The C# regex API can be quite confusing. There are *groups* and *captures*:

- A *group* represents a capturing group, it's used to extract a substring from the text
- There can be several *captures* per group, if the group appears inside a quantifier.

The hierarchy is:

- Match

  - Group

    - Capture

(a match can have several groups, and each group can have several captures)

For example:

```
Subject: aabcabbc
Pattern: ^(?:(a+b+)c)+$
```

In this example, there is only one group: `(a+b+)`. This group is inside a quantifier, and is matched twice. It generates two *captures*: `aab` and `abb`:

```
aabcabbc
^^^ ^^^
Cap1  Cap2
```

When a group is not inside of a quantifier, it generates only one capture. In your case, you have 3 groups, and each group captures once. You can use `match.Groups[1].Value`, `match.Groups[2].Value` and `match.Groups[3].Value` to extract the 3 substrings you're interested in, without resorting to the *capture* notion at all.

Comment: Wouldn't it be match.Groups[0].Value 1, 2 because of 0 based index?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere the group at index 0 represents the whole match. Capturing groups start at index 1.

Answer (score 11):

Match results can be complicated to understand. I wrote this code to assist my understanding of what had been found and where. The intention is that pieces of the output (from the lines marked with `//**`) can be copied into the program to make use of values found in the match.

```
public static void DisplayMatchResults(Match match)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match has {0} captures", match.Captures.Count);

    int groupNo = 0;
    foreach (Group mm in match.Groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Group {0,2} has {1,2} captures '{2}'", groupNo, mm.Captures.Count, mm.Value);

        int captureNo = 0;
        foreach (Capture cc in mm.Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("       Capture {0,2} '{1}'", captureNo, cc);
            captureNo++;
        }
        groupNo++;
    }

    groupNo = 0;
    foreach (Group mm in match.Groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    match.Groups[{0}].Value == \"{1}\"", groupNo, match.Groups[groupNo].Value); //**
        groupNo++;
    }

    groupNo = 0;
    foreach (Group mm in match.Groups)
    {
        int captureNo = 0;
        foreach (Capture cc in mm.Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    match.Groups[{0}].Captures[{1}].Value == \"{2}\"", groupNo, captureNo, match.Groups[groupNo].Captures[captureNo].Value); //**
            captureNo++;
        }
        groupNo++;
    }
}
```

A simple example of using this method, given this input:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("/([A-Za-z]+)/(\\d+)");
String text = "some/directory/Pictures/Houses/12/apple/banana/"
            + "cherry/345/damson/elderberry/fig/678/gooseberry";
Match match = regex.Match(text);
DisplayMatchResults(match);
```

The output is:

```
Match has 1 captures
  Group  0 has  1 captures '/Houses/12'
       Capture  0 '/Houses/12'
  Group  1 has  1 captures 'Houses'
       Capture  0 'Houses'
  Group  2 has  1 captures '12'
       Capture  0 '12'
    match.Groups[0].Value == "/Houses/12"
    match.Groups[1].Value == "Houses"
    match.Groups[2].Value == "12"
    match.Groups[0].Captures[0].Value == "/Houses/12"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value == "Houses"
    match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value == "12"
```

Suppose that we want to find all matches of the above regular expression in the above text. Then we can use a `MatchCollection` in code such as:

```
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);
for (int ii = 0; ii < matches.Count; ii++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match[{0}]  // of 0..{1}:", ii, matches.Count-1);
    RegexMatchDisplay.DisplayMatchResults(matches[ii]);
}
```

The output from this is:

```
Match[0]  // of 0..2:
Match has 1 captures
  Group  0 has  1 captures '/Houses/12/'
       Capture  0 '/Houses/12/'
  Group  1 has  1 captures 'Houses'
       Capture  0 'Houses'
  Group  2 has  1 captures '12'
       Capture  0 '12'
    match.Groups[0].Value == "/Houses/12/"
    match.Groups[1].Value == "Houses"
    match.Groups[2].Value == "12"
    match.Groups[0].Captures[0].Value == "/Houses/12/"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value == "Houses"
    match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value == "12"
Match[1]  // of 0..2:
Match has 1 captures
  Group  0 has  1 captures '/cherry/345/'
       Capture  0 '/cherry/345/'
  Group  1 has  1 captures 'cherry'
       Capture  0 'cherry'
  Group  2 has  1 captures '345'
       Capture  0 '345'
    match.Groups[0].Value == "/cherry/345/"
    match.Groups[1].Value == "cherry"
    match.Groups[2].Value == "345"
    match.Groups[0].Captures[0].Value == "/cherry/345/"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value == "cherry"
    match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value == "345"
Match[2]  // of 0..2:
Match has 1 captures
  Group  0 has  1 captures '/fig/678/'
       Capture  0 '/fig/678/'
  Group  1 has  1 captures 'fig'
       Capture  0 'fig'
  Group  2 has  1 captures '678'
       Capture  0 '678'
    match.Groups[0].Value == "/fig/678/"
    match.Groups[1].Value == "fig"
    match.Groups[2].Value == "678"
    match.Groups[0].Captures[0].Value == "/fig/678/"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value == "fig"
    match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value == "678"
```

Hence:

```
    matches[1].Groups[0].Value == "/cherry/345/"
    matches[1].Groups[1].Value == "cherry"
    matches[1].Groups[2].Value == "345"
    matches[1].Groups[0].Captures[0].Value == "/cherry/345/"
    matches[1].Groups[1].Captures[0].Value == "cherry"
    matches[1].Groups[2].Captures[0].Value == "345"
```

Similarly for `matches[0]` and `matches[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string pattern = @"[(]?(\d{3})[)]?[ -.]?(\d{3})[ -.]?(\d{4})";

System.Console.WriteLine("What is your phone number?");
string phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();

while (!Regex.IsMatch(phoneNumber, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bad Input");
    phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
}

var match = Regex.Match(phoneNumber, pattern);
if (match.Groups.Count == 4)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Number matched : "+match.Groups[0].Value);
    System.Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value + "-" + match.Groups[2].Value + "-" + match.Groups[3].Value);
}
```