# C# Regex Match Array

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

so this is my first real time using C# and I am having some troubles using regex.
So I have a string like this:

`string str = "test=CAPTURE1; test2=CAPTURE2; ......."`

I am capturing everything between `=` and `;` so:

`var matches = Regex.Matches(str, "=([^;]*);/g");`

However, I am not able to get the results out of an array:

`string str2 = matches[0].Value;`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**
So here is what I am trying to implement this to (using @Jason Evans code):

```
string connection = "Server=localhost;Database=dbTest;User Id=hello;Password=world;";            
var matches = Regex.Matches(connection, "(?<Key>[^=]*)=(?<Value>[^;]*)");

string server = matches[0].Groups["Data"].Value;
string db = matches[1].Groups["Data"].Value;
string un = matches[2].Groups["Data"].Value;
string pw = matches[3].Groups["Data"].Value;           

MsSqlConnectionParameters param = (MsSqlConnectionParameters)e.ConnectionParameters;
param.ServerName = server;
param.DatabaseName = db;
param.UserName = un;
param.Password = pw;
```

This is still not working for some reason, even though I believe this is right.

**EDIT2:** What's weird is that this works (using same data)...I'm stumped:

```
string[] test = { "localhost", "dbTest", "hello", "world" };

MsSqlConnectionParameters param = (MsSqlConnectionParameters)e.ConnectionParameters;

param.ServerName = test[0];
param.DatabaseName = test[1];
param.UserName = test[2];
param.Password = test[3];
```

Comment: The global flag is implied by the `Regex.Matches()` method. See here for using global flags though, it's not done like JS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b49yw9s8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I tried you example removing the `/g` at the end of your regex and it worked as expected. What are you using that for?

Comment: @Luiso i've update my post so you can see my implementation

Comment: For more info on getting the results of matches see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444640/how-to-read-regex-captures-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "test=CAPTURE1; test2=CAPTURE2";

            var matches = Regex.Matches(str, "(?<Key>[^=]*)=(?<Value>[^;]*)");

            string str2 = matches[0].Groups["Key"].Value;
            string str3 = matches[0].Groups["Value"].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I use a named capture group `(?<Key>)` and `(?<Data>)` to catch the text before and after the '='. That way you can grab the individual part of the string.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is right - but I am still having issues passing the values to what I need. I have updated my post to include my implementation.