# Inconsistent result of regex match

Tags: c#, regex

I want to parse from this `1h30m45s` to collection of matches with groups `1h`, `30m`, `45s`.

I managed something like this:

`var matches = Regex.Match(input, @"(\d+[ms|s|m|h|d])");`

Unfortunately I am getting groups: `1h` and `1h`. What's wrong there? I tried the same on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SIjjEh/2) and it seems to work.

Comment: `Groups[0]` is the complete match, while `Groups[1]` is the first capturing group

Comment: @Xerillio So why in c# `30m` is not in any group?

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444640/how-to-read-regex-captures-in-c-sharp) for some more understanding of groups, captures and matches.

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting one match by calling `Match`. The two `1h`s are just group 0 and group 1. And group 0 is the same as the match itself.

You need to get all the matches by calling `Matches`. Then you can convert all the matched strings into a list like this:

```
var list = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+[ms|s|m|h|d]").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

The group is unnecessary.