# Is there a way to have Regex.Match provide only the intended capture group?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

The way c# regex.match seems to work is the only capture group values return include the entire string matched against the pattern. Instead, I just want $1. Now I have to do this second step process to clean up the result. Is there a cleaner way where it can be reduced to 1 step?

```
var lineText = @"Reservations 03Mar19";
var m1Pattern = @"^\s*Reservations.*\b(\d{2}\w{3}\d{2})$";

Match m1 = Regex.Match(lineText, m1Pattern);
if (m1.Success) MyDate = Regex.Replace(m1.Groups[0].Captures[0].Value, m1Pattern, @"$1");
```

Comment: `if (m1.Success) { MyDate = m1.Groups[1].Value; }`

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444640/how-to-read-regex-captures-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

you can use `?:` in your groups that tells regex not to capture that group:

```
(?:this group is not captured(but this one is))
```

Compare this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IglJqC/1) and [this One](https://regex101.com/r/IglJqC/2)

And Here is the [C# Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kqQuB4)

Comment: Your demos work the way expect a regex to work. I don't think C# regex match works with capture groups. I get no response out of including (?:bla bla bla ) or (bla bla bla) - it just doesn't care. I have to use the replace to get captures to work in c#.

Comment: @user2741445 have a look at [this C# demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kqQuB4). what you want is in $2, but not capturing the first group, its in $1.

Comment: Yes, Regex.Replace does work for capturing groups. Thanks for the C# demo. The one thing I still need is to know if the capture was successful or not. Regex.Replace doesn't do that. I just returns a string that I will have to further evaluate. Regex.Match tells me if the entire pattern was a match or not. As far as I can tell, I'll always need at least 2 lines of code using c#: (match, and then replace) or something like that. In a scripting language, it can be done in one.

Comment: I made changes to my C3 demo, please have look at it, it detects if replace has been made or not

Comment: That is pretty close. The result is wrapped with a if statement to further evaluate. In my case, I need a variable set to the result if the capture was successful. If not, the result needs to remain untouched.  Perhaps something like: (regex.replace(..) = txt) ? results = $1 : nope;.

Comment: exactly as you said: `result =  (regex.replace(..) = txt) ? "Set" : "Not Set";` or if you need a boolean value just `result =  (regex.replace(..) = txt);`

Answer (score 0):

Using `MyDate = m1.Groups[1].Value` should do what you want.

Comment: MyDate = m1.Groups[0].Value is the same as MyDate = m1.Groups[0].Captures[0].Value (at least for my case). The problem is I only want a subset of the matched value and used to scripting languages where I can do that without extra code.