# How to capture everything in a string into separate groups in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have some data in a file and I am using `Regex` to get individual elements and remove all the `\r\n` between the `<opening>` and `</closing>` tags.

But when i am trying to select the `elements` separately, at the end, the whole data is getting selected as one group.

This is my Regex:

```
(<([ph0-9figc]+)>)([a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß[:punct:] \n\r\t])+(<\/\2>)
```

Sample with [Input Data](https://regex101.com/r/c7y9zT/1)

Comment: That data does not looks like it should be published somehow.. + Regex is not suited for matching nested data

Comment: Don't use regex to parse XML.  Use an XML parser.

Comment: Your description seems to fit HTML format, look into .net related HTML classes. I guess you wanted to say "between the `<data>` (opening tag) and `</data>` (closing tag)"

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444640/how-to-read-regex-captures-in-c-sharp) for some code that may help you understand what text has been saved into the captures.

Answer (score 6):

It may not be the best idea to do this task with regular expressions, especially for replacing new lines.

If we really have to, we might want to capture those tags one by one. For instance, this expression only captures the `p` tags using three capturing groups `()`:

```
(<p>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/p>)
```

[image]

#### [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dSkqlF/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

We can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(<p>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/p>)/gm;
const str = `<p>
<st>Liebe stern-Redaktion,
</st> 
<i>Liebe stern-Redaktion,</i> warum schreiben Sie nicht, was wirklich freitags whrend der Protest-Demos am Grenzzaun passiert? Wie die Familien der Mrder fr jede gettete jdische Person belohnt werden? Oder ber die Feuerballons, die aus dem Gazastreifen in den Sden Israels geschickt werden? Brita Singh, Scheeel</p>
<fig>
<img src="images/img_8-1.jpg" width="596" height="428" alt="" />
<fc>
<i>stern</i> Nr. 10/2019, Bild der Woche: Kindertrauer im Gazastreifen</fc>
</fig> 
<p>
<i>Sehr geehrte Frau Singh,</i> bei Demonstrationen am Grenzzaun starben laut Bericht der UN-Kommission in neun Monaten 35 Kinder durch Schüsse israelischer Soldaten. Zwei Journalisten und drei Sanitäter wurden erschossen, über 6000 Menschen verletzt. Israel hat gerade Ermittlungen zu elf der Todesfälle aufgenommen. Dagegen hat es in dem Zeitraum kein israelisches Todesopfer am Grenzzaun zu Gaza gegeben. Die Hamas pflegt einen Märtyrerkult und belohnt Morde mit Geld; israelische Sicherheitskräfte zerstören Häuser von Angehörigen palästinensischer Attentäter. Beides fördert den Hass. Opfer sind Menschen wie das Mädchen auf diesem Bild. Der <i>stern</i> hat keinen einseitigen Blick auf die Komplexität des Nahostkonflikts wir schauen stets auf beide Seiten. <i>Mit freundlichen Grüßen Cornelia Fuchs, Ressortleiterin Ausland</i></p>
<p>Eine liebevolle Mutter will, dass ihr Kind glücklich ist, egal, ob sie sein Leben versteht. Alles andere ist Egoismus und keine Mutterliebe. </p>
<p>Annemarie Fischer, Wielenbach</p>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### C# Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(<p>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/p>)";
        string input = @"<p>
<st>Liebe stern-Redaktion,
</st> 
<i>Liebe stern-Redaktion,</i> warum schreiben Sie nicht, was wirklich freitags whrend der Protest-Demos am Grenzzaun passiert? Wie die Familien der Mrder fr jede gettete jdische Person belohnt werden? Oder ber die Feuerballons, die aus dem Gazastreifen in den Sden Israels geschickt werden? Brita Singh, Scheeel</p>
<fig>
<img src=""images/img_8-1.jpg"" width=""596"" height=""428"" alt="""" />
<fc>
<i>stern</i> Nr. 10/2019, Bild der Woche: Kindertrauer im Gazastreifen</fc>
</fig>  
<p>
<i>Sehr geehrte Frau Singh,</i> bei Demonstrationen am Grenzzaun starben laut Bericht der UN-Kommission in neun Monaten 35 Kinder durch Schüsse israelischer Soldaten. Zwei Journalisten und drei Sanitäter wurden erschossen, über 6000 Menschen verletzt. Israel hat gerade Ermittlungen zu elf der Todesfälle aufgenommen. Dagegen hat es in dem Zeitraum kein israelisches Todesopfer am Grenzzaun zu Gaza gegeben. Die Hamas pflegt einen Märtyrerkult und belohnt Morde mit Geld; israelische Sicherheitskräfte zerstören Häuser von Angehörigen palästinensischer Attentäter. Beides fördert den Hass. Opfer sind Menschen wie das Mädchen auf diesem Bild. Der <i>stern</i> hat keinen einseitigen Blick auf die Komplexität des Nahostkonflikts wir schauen stets auf beide Seiten. <i>Mit freundlichen Grüßen Cornelia Fuchs, Ressortleiterin Ausland</i></p>
<p>Eine liebevolle Mutter will, dass ihr Kind glücklich ist, egal, ob sie sein Leben versteht. Alles andere ist Egoismus und keine Mutterliebe. </p>
<p>Annemarie Fischer, Wielenbach</p>";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to accept the extra "_" and other white space characters then I simplified your pattern as follows:

```
var pat = @"(<(?'tag'[ph0-9figc]+)>)(?'body'([\wäöüÄÖÜß\p{P}\s])+)(<\/\k'tag'>)";
```

And the regular expression removing the CR-LF is:

```
var body = m.Groups["body"].Value
   .Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ")
   .Replace("\r", " ")
   .Replace("\n", " ");
var tag = m.Groups["tag"].Value;
var noCrLf = re.Replace(text, m => $"<{tag}>{body}</{tag}>");
```

Though looking at your data, I may not have understood what you are after.  One of your tags, for example,  is not matched by your tag pattern "[ph0-9figc]+".  If I did not understand your concern, please straighten me out.