# Why does this Regex only return one capture?

Tags: c#, regex

I've looked at answers to similar questions and they didn't help me-  I'm confused about how captures should work.   Here's my code:

```
var searchMe = "### applez ### airplanez #### apez";
var m = Regex.Match(searchMe, @"(a.+?z)");

Debug.WriteLine($"Found {m.Groups.Count} groups");
Debug.WriteLine($"and {m.Captures.Count} captures");
Debug.WriteLine($"and {m.Groups[1].Captures.Count} group[1] captures");
```

output:

```
Found 2 groups
and 1 captures
and 1 group[1] captures
```

When I try the same text and regex on http://regexstorm.net/tester, I get 3 matches.   Why am I seeing only 1 match and 1 capture in my code?

**EDIT**:  The reason is that I was using Regex.Match instead of Regex.Matches.

Comment: `var m = Regex.Matches(searchMe, @"(a.+?z)");`, note `Matches` (all, not just one `Match`)

Comment: I've never liked the Regex library in C#.  Not intuitive.

Comment: What is the value of the capture? You may find it's doing a greedy match.

Comment: @Darksider It is not the case here.

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27444808/546871

Comment: @DmitryBychenko for the win!     Jonesopolis - definitely not intuitive!