# How to write REGEX for "componentStatusId==2|3,screeningOwnerId>0"

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Need to get three strings from the below mentioned string, need the possible solution in C# and ASP.NET:

```
"componentStatusId==2|3,screeningOwnerId>0"
```

I need to get '2','3' and '0' using a regular expression in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is the numbers from a string then you could use the regex in this code:

```
        string re = "(?:\\b(\\d+)\\b[^\\d]*)+";
        Regex regex = new Regex(re);

        string input = "componentStatusId==2|3,screeningOwnerId>0";

        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);

        for (int ii = 0; ii < matches.Count; ii++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match[{0}]  // of 0..{1}:", ii, matches.Count - 1);
            DisplayMatchResults(matches[ii]);
        }
```

Function `DisplayMatchResults` is taken from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444640/how-to-read-regex-captures-in-c-sharp/27444808#27444808).

The Console output from the above is:

```
Match[0]  // of 0..0:
Match has 1 captures
  Group  0 has  1 captures '2|3,screeningOwnerId>0'
       Capture  0 '2|3,screeningOwnerId>0'
  Group  1 has  3 captures '0'
       Capture  0 '2'
       Capture  1 '3'
       Capture  2 '0'
    match.Groups[0].Value == "2|3,screeningOwnerId>0"
    match.Groups[1].Value == "0"
    match.Groups[0].Captures[0].Value == "2|3,screeningOwnerId>0"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value == "2"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[1].Value == "3"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[2].Value == "0"
```

Hence the numbers can be seen in `match.Groups[1].Captures[...]`.

---

---

Another possibility is to use `Regex.Split` where the pattern is "non digits". The results from the code below will need post processing to remove empty strings. Note that `Regex.Split` does not have the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` of the string `Split` method.

```
        string input = "componentStatusId==2|3,screeningOwnerId>0";
        string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, "[^\\d]+");
        for (int ii = 0; ii < numbers.Length; ii++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:  '{1}'", ii, numbers[ii]);
        }
```

The output from this is:

```
0:  ''
1:  '2'
2:  '34'
3:  '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following regex and capture your values from group 1, 2 and 3.

```
componentStatusId==(\d+)\|(\d+),screeningOwnerId>(\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ImGHUh/1)

For generalizing `componentStatusId` and `screeningOwnerId` with any string, you can use `\w+` in the regex and make it more general.

```
\w+==(\d+)\|(\d+),\w+>(\d+)
```

[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ImGHUh/2)

Comment: Thanks @pushpesh, is there any possible way to convert 'componentStatusId' 'screeningOwnerId' to regex, so that it could be applied on any other alteranting string!

Comment: Yea sure, Can you add some more samples in your post so I can generalize the regex. For generalizing you can use `\w+` instead of hard coded string.