# How to capture all matched pattern that surround by another pattern?

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

For example:
I want to find all numbers from "aa12345aa" that surround by "aa".

I tried:

```
"aa12345aa".matchAll(/aa(\d)*?aa/ig)
```

However, this will result only 1 array that only capture last number, which is `5`

```
['aa12345aa', '5', index: 0, input: 'aa12345aa', groups: undefined]
```

I want to capture all numbers, so result will be:

```
['aa12345aa', '1','2','3','4','5' index: 0, input: 'aa12345aa', groups: undefined]
```

Any suggestion will appreciate, Thanks!!

Comment: You cannot get a variable number of capture groups. You could capture all digits in one group though. Why is this tagged with `c#`?

Comment: @trincot I want to achieve it on C#, but for simplicity here, I copy some output from browser console for displaying, but anyway they are still RegExp

Comment: Reading the comment on the current answer, the data that you use is different and this is just an example with `aa` Can you update the question with the actual data that you are using and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asker states, in a comment, that their goal is C# code.

Using the RegEx from the question, this C# code extracts each of the digits.

```
string input = "aa12345aa";
Regex regex = new Regex("aa(\\d)*?aa");
Match match = regex.Match(input);
DisplayMatchResults(match);
```

Note that function `DisplayMatchResults` is taken from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27444808/546871).

The output from the above is shown below. It shows each of the digits saved to separate elements in the match results.

```
Match has 1 captures
  Group  0 has  1 captures 'aa12345aa'
       Capture  0 'aa12345aa'
  Group  1 has  5 captures '5'
       Capture  0 '1'
       Capture  1 '2'
       Capture  2 '3'
       Capture  3 '4'
       Capture  4 '5'
    match.Groups[0].Value == "aa12345aa"
    match.Groups[1].Value == "5"
    match.Groups[0].Captures[0].Value == "aa12345aa"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value == "1"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[1].Value == "2"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[2].Value == "3"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[3].Value == "4"
    match.Groups[1].Captures[4].Value == "5"
```

Comment: Good to know that it can capture all results on C#, while it only captures last one on JS, probably need some trick on JS.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand. You want all numbers between aa or anything between aa?

```
aa(\d+)aa
```

or
aa(.*?)aa
This is group1. After I think you can break it in numbers.

Comment: This is just an example, the one I am working is from ".......<<[1][2][3]>>............", get "1", "2","3", and the "..." here is other strings not interesting. I can use string splitting and more logic to do it, but just want to achieve it directly using RegExp.